# What is the difference between these two casting options on macbook?

Tags: macbook-pro, streaming

I am using a MacBook and casting to my TV via Elmedia Player. There are always these two options, which seem to do exactly the same thing.

[image]

Comment: The upper icon is for Apple TV and other Airplay  compatible devices. The lover icon is for all others

Comment: One of the options uses the built-in Airplay and the other is found via local network